# Getting a type mismatch error in vbScript

Tags: java, vbscript

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments

dim rec

rec = args.Item(1)&" "&args.Item(2)

return rec
```

I wrote this simple vbScript above, then when I try to call this code from Java...

```
import java.io.*;

 class RuntimeDemo{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Process p=null;

   try {  

   p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript D:/AS/VBScripts/Sample1.vbs " + args[0] +" " + args[1] + " " + args[2]);

   }
   catch( IOException e ) {

      System.out.println(e);

      System.exit(0);
   }
    p.waitFor();  

    InputStream in = p.getInputStream(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {

                System.out.println("" + in.read());
```

I get an error `"Type mismatch 'return'"`.  Where exactly is this coming from, and what would be the proper solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is likely coming from trying to set "return" to a value.  VBScript does not support "return".  If you want to return a value from a function you would construct it like so:

```
function GetParams()
  dim wsh, args, rec
  set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  set args = wscript.arguments
  if args.Count <= 0 then
    GetParams = ""
    exit function
  end if

  if args.Count >= 2 then
    rec = args(1) & " " & args(2)
  elseif args.count = 1
    rec = args(1)
  else
    rec = ""
  end if
  GetParams = rec
end function
```

In VB, and vbScript, your "return value" is set by assigning the value to the name of the function, as I have done above.

Of course, you need to be careful, because if no argument 2 is passed in, then you will end up with an array subscript error, so always use the args.Count, as I demonstrated above BEFORE you attempt to access the parameters individually.

If you have a more specific question, or error, or explain what you are doing, we can probably get you a better answer...

Comment: The first part of your answer is spot on, but the second part is wrong. The documentation for [WshArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x49bex47%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) isn't really clear on this, but a quick test shows that when you try to access a non-existent argument, WScript just throws an error (it does not return Null). Also, Null can be concatenated with a string; it gets treated like a zero-length string ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)).

Comment: Ah yes...  NO IDEA what I was thinking when I wrote that!  Duh.. of COURSE if you try and access a parameter that does not exist, it will throw an error, because it is in an array, and that element will not exist.  Thanks for pointing that out, I will edit the answer to ensure accurate information...